# jQuery finding deeply nested input element

Tags: jquery, asp.net, forms, traversal, descendant

I'm using a form control in my project listed [here](http://www.obout.com/SuperForm/aspnet_firstlook_checkout.aspx)

When I include it in my page it generates a whole whack of dynamic html to format everything nicely. However, I am trying to apply `jQuery datepicker` to a few of the input elements inside the form and I have no idea how to select the inputs I want.

I've nested the SuperForm directly inside a `div` called "`bookings`" so I know that I can use that as a starting point but I need to go through all of the descendants of that div till I find the right inputs, I know in which order they appear so I assume I can use nth-child(x) in here somewhere but so far I haven't had any luck. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

SOLVED! Here is my solution:

```
$("#bookings :input[type='text']:eq(2)").datepicker({...});
```

Comment: can we an example of the html that is generated?

Comment: why don't you apply a class or id to the input elem?

Comment: The input element is dynamically generated I can't apply a client side id to it.

Comment: if you give us the code that is generated and the `inputs` you want selected we can help you from there

Comment: you can inspect those elements, lookup their ids and locate them, simple!...from the look at the page, i found only 2 inputs, where you possibly want datepicker - they have the titles 'Expiration Year' and 'Expiration Month'....the id of the latter one is 'ob_iDdlSuperForm1_ExpirationMonthTB'...and the former's is 'ob_iDdlSuperForm1_ExpirationYearTB'....your problem solved.

Comment: did that work? please inform that at least!

Comment: No sorry, the ids are dynamically generated based on where they are placed in the page. Because I am using this inside of a user control it is different across every page. For example: on one page the id is "ctl00$SideBarContent$Bookings1$BookingForm$BookingForm_checkOut"

Comment: aww! that's a bit of trouble then...but i guess the tooltips are unique (or to solve your problem - please make them unique!)...so you can find an element using $('input[title:MY_TOOLTIP_TEXT_WHICH_IS_UNIQUE]')

Comment: I figured it out, check original post for solution. Turned out to be pretty easy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED! Here is my solution:

```
$("#bookings :input[type='text']:eq(2)").datepicker({...});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply a class, attribute or id to the elements that you want or check every element this way.

```
$('#bookings input').each(function () {
   //Check here

 });
```

Comment: I know that the inputs I need to affect are the 2nd and 3rd ones inside the form. Is there a way to simply return all input elements nested inside the "bookings" div and select the 2nd and 3rd ones?

Comment: why don't you try $('#bookings input:nth-child(2), #bookings input:nth-child(3)')? that will give all the 3rd and 2nd inputs, even the nested ones

Answer (score 0):

You will obviously need some identifier/selector to filter your input elements.

```
$('#bookings').find('.applyDatePicker').datepicker({...});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the new input types supported in HTML5.

The new input types are:

- color
- date
- datetime
- datetime-local
- email
- month
- number
- range
- search
- tel
- time
- url
- week

If you set those to date (or datetime) you can select all of the elements using:

```
$('input[type="date"]').each(function(index,element){
   $(element).datepicker...
}
```

Comment: This is not useful as if you may have noticed I mentioned the inputs were being dynamically created by the form control I am using... Therefore I have no control over what type of input type is assigned to them. Also, the issue is solved as indicated by my solution in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

You right when using simple selector but if your main selector is complicated probably you couldn't use input selector inside main selector, So it's better to use

```
.find(" :input[type='text']")
```

for example in sortable scenario if main selector like this:

```
$("#ulId").children('li:not(.ui-sortable-placeholder)')
```

you couldn't got any element if you coding as below:

```
$("#ulId").children('li:not(.ui-sortable-placeholder) :input[type='text']')
```

but we could use this:

```
$("#ulId").children('li:not(.ui-sortable-placeholder)').find(" :input[type='text']")
```

Hope this help.